# Finding the span or eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Im having trouble understanding how to find the eigenspaces of a matrix.

$\;A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\1&2&1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

rref ($2I_3-A$) = $\;\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

E(2) = span $\;\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$,$\;\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

I understand how to get the second vector

$v_1$ = -t

$v_2$ = 0

$v_3$ = t

which is $t$$\;\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

I dont understand where $\;\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ comes from. Thanks!

Comment: We have **two** free variables: one for the third column, and one for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second vector is false. It should be $(0,1,0)$ instead. 
You can choose both second and third coordinate freely, then you compute the first.  The set of all solutions is $\{(-t,s,t)\colon s,t \in \mathbb{R}\}$. A basis of this is obtained by choosing $s=0, t=1$ and $s=1, t=0$ (but you could make a different choice too).

Comment: Which one is false? [-1 0 1] or [1 0 0]? This is from my textbook.

Comment: Yeah, sorry,  the "second" was not very clear. But now as you write it in the comment it is the second that is false.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! My textbook really sucks. The misprints are driving me crazy.